# Area of Bounding Box of an object matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have objets have different shapes and my aim is to find ratio between object area and its Bounding Box area. There is no problem to find object area but I did not find a way to get Bounding Box area.

Is there any way or any exist function in matlab to calculate Bounding Box area?

Answer (score 3):

But, you know the bounding box? If you dont, use [`regionprops(Imgbw,'BoundingBox')`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/regionprops.html#bqkf8hf)
And you will get it.

Once you have it, its kinda easy. Is just computing the area of a square. Regionprops will give you `[x y]`  and `[x_width y_width]`. Im sure you are capable of calculating the area of a square with the size of its sides.

Comment: @AnderBirugi I know the bounding box but it gives me four value like 246,500000000000 270,500000000000 79 82. What are these? How can I calculate area of bounding box by using these values?

Comment: They are the upper-left coordinates of the bounding box and the length of the sides of the bounding box. If you remember 8 year old mathematics, if you just multiply the sides of the square you get the are of it. So in your case, the are of the square is 79*82. Thats it! ;)

Comment: No problem about calculation :) I meant how I can access to these values but I found a way to access to values. Thank you :)

Comment: @sigara Accept the answer if you like it ;)